# Why doesn't JPA repeat persist method throw an exception?

Tags: jpa, exception, eclipselink, persist

```
Product product = new Product();
product.setName( "foo" );
product.setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf( 4.5 ) );
pm.create( product ); // pm delegates calls to an entity manager object using persist method and tx is immediately commited after the call

List<Product> products = pm.findAllProducts();
products.stream().forEach( System.out::println ); // New product is listed too.

pm.create( product ); // Causes no exception! But, as per API, it should.

products = pm.findAllProducts(); // Fetch successful
products.stream().forEach( System.out::println ); // No difference from first print.
```

As per [persistence API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-), if an entity alredy exists, persist(called from `pm.create`) throw's `EntityExistsException`, but its not happening as per code.

1. Pesistence provider(PP) - EclipseLink.
2. Why is PP ignoring repeat persist?
3. In what circumstances does a PP choose to throw an exception?

**EDIT:**

**Product.java**

**NOTE:**

1. Excluded getters and setters(for all fields) and toString() for brevity.
2. I tried my best to format code as per guidelines, but its not happening, please bear.

> @Entity @Table(name = "PRODUCTS") @XmlRootElement @NamedQueries({
>       @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p")
>       , @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.id = :id")
>       , @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.name like :name")
>       , @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByPrice", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.price = :price")
>       , @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByBestBefore", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.bestBefore = :bestBefore")
>       , @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByVersion", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.version = :version")
>       , @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findTotal", query = "SELECT count(p.id), sum(p.price) FROM Product p WHERE p.id in :ids" ) })
>
> public class Product implements Serializable {
>
> ```
> private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
> @Id
> @Basic(optional = false)
> @NotNull
> @SequenceGenerator( name="pidGen", sequenceName="PID_SEQ", allocationSize=1 )
> @GeneratedValue( strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="pidGen" )
> private Integer id;
> @Basic(optional = false)
> @NotNull
> @Size(min = 3, max = 40, message="{prod.name}")
> private String name;
> // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
> @Basic(optional = false)
> @NotNull
> @Max( value=1000, message="{prod.price.max}")
> @Min( value=1, message="{prod.price.min}")
> private BigDecimal price;
> @Column(name = "BEST_BEFORE")
> @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
> //private Date bestBefore;
> private LocalDate bestBefore;
> @Version
> private Integer version;
>
> public Product() {
> }
>
> public Product(Integer id) {
>     this.id = id;
> }
>
> public Product(Integer id, String name, BigDecimal price) {
>     this.id = id;
>     this.name = name;
>     this.price = price;
> }
>
>
>
> @Override
> public int hashCode() {
>     int hash = 0;
>     hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
>     return hash;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean equals(Object object) {
>     // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
>     if (!(object instanceof Product)) {
>         return false;
>     }
>     Product other = (Product) object;
>     if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
>         return false;
>     }
>     return true;
> }
>
>
>  }
> ```

Comment: `pm` is an instance of what?

Comment: show the product entity

Comment: @AlanHay `pm` is a POJO - helper/utility/delegate. `create` method: `public void create( @Valid Product product ) { em.getTransaction().begin(); em.persist( product ); em.getTransaction().commit(); }`

Comment: @MaciejKowalski Updated OP with same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [JPA Spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf):

> 1. If X is a new entity, it becomes managed. The entity X will be entered into the database at or
>      before transaction commit or as a result of the flush operation.
> 2. If X is a preexisting managed entity, it is ignored by the persist operation (...)
> 3. If X is a detached object, the EntityExistsException may be thrown when the persist
>      operation is invoked, or the EntityExistsException or another PersistenceException may be thrown at flush or commit time

When you invoke `EntityManager.persist(product)`, `product` becomes a managed entity (#1). Any subsequent calls to `EntityManager.persist(product)` are ignored, as described in #2. The final point applies only when you try to invoke `persist()` on a **detached** entity.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski Ah! Now I see the OP is starting and commiting the transaction inside `pm.create()`. Yes, you're absolutely right

Comment: @MaciejKowalski on second thought though, this is an application-managed EM, so  by definition it has extended scope. Doesn't that mean `product` remains in the persistence context until the EM is cleared or closed?

Comment: We do not know that. Possibly you may be right. But that is hidden inside the create method

Comment: #2 is acting upon the situation. Interested users: - if a new entity is persisted and updated, then if `persist` method is called on it, persistence provider will update it. Code(compare with OP): `Product product = new Product();
product.setName( "foo1" );
product.setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf( 4.5 ) );
pm.create( product );
List<Product> products = pm.findAllProducts();
products.stream().forEach( System.out::println );
product.setName( "foo2" );
pm.create( product );
products = pm.findAllProducts();
products.stream().forEach( System.out::println );`

Comment: Section '3.2.2Persisting an Entity Instance' of the spec(see link in answer) has explanation.